# Running django application on Compute Engine machine and expose it to the internet

Tags: django, nginx

I have a Django application that is running on port 8000 on a GCE instance like this:

```
 gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 AImage.wsgi:application
[2024-01-05 03:59:35 +0000] [158846] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2024-01-05 03:59:35 +0000] [158846] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (158846)
[2024-01-05 03:59:35 +0000] [158846] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2024-01-05 03:59:35 +0000] [158847] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 158847
```

I have created a file here:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/AImage
```

and created this symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/AImage /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

with this content:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <GCE IP>;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

and restart nginx service. From what I can tell this should be enough for the app to be accessed through GCE IP on the browser. I can ping GCE IP through console from my local machine just fine, but when I access it through the browser it keeps saying This site can’t be reached.I'm not sure if there's anything else I need to do before it's available.

Comment: GCE has its own firewall. Did you check the box when creating the VM to allow HTTP/HTTPS traffic through?

Comment: I did not. However running using does actually serve the webapp, so I don't think it's a firewall issue, unless ngrok modifies the firewall that I didn't know about.

Comment: I believe ngrok uses outbound connections to host an app, which are allowed by default.

Comment: I see. I will look into the firewall issue then. Thanks.